# If $x\lt 2$, what is the maximum value of $x$?

Tags: inequality

I need to substitute $x$ for a maximum value, but I don't know what it would be. There are proofs that show $1.99\dots$ is $2$, so that can't be it... any answers would be appreciated :)

Edit: Sorry I should have added context:

I'm trying to prove that $a^2+3a+2-x > a+2$, where $x\lt2$, and $a\gt0$

Comment: This is a funny thing. When you look at the set of all $x$ strictly less than 2, this set *has no maximum*. There is no largest element of that set.

Comment: By asking the question, you are motivating the study of supremum, limits and all of calculus :)

Comment: The *least upper bound* of that set is $2$, however.  You should explain the context better, esp. why you "need to substitute $x$ for a maximum value".

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum value, but $2$ is an upper bound.  Generally where you are trying to substitute a maximum, an upper bound is fine, too.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that a^2+3a+2-x > a+2, where x<2, and a>0.

Comment: Yes, here you can say $a^2+3a+2-x \gt a^2+3a+2-2$, so if you can prove $a^2+3a \gt a+2$ you are home.  Unfortunately, it is not true for $a$ small.  Substitute in $x=1.99, a=0.01$.  The left side is barely greater than $0$, the right is greater than $2$

Comment: Ohhh I see, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

We say that if say $x_n = 2-1/n$, then $\sup x_n = 2$, (the supremum of $x_n$ is $2$). $x_n$ can be as close to $2$ as we want, but it can never equal $2$.

A similar idea is from topology, the concept of a limit point. If $X = \{x : 0\le x \lt 2\}$ then $2$ is a limit point of $X$.

A different way of looking at the problem is: if $\epsilon\gt0$, can $2+\epsilon=2$?

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a max. value; the 2 is just an Upper bound (Least upperbound this case).